# soap/rest C library for embedded device

Tags: c, soap, embedded, embeddedwebserver

Is there any tiny soap/rest library which works on uIP ?? I have seen the libsoap but it works on nanohttp. I want a uIP compatible library written in C....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you use following libs?

- [cSOAP](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/) ([Sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csoap/))
- [XML-RPC C](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) (not soap, but maybe you can use it)
- [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) (available for C too - biut i guess it's to big)